# Azure function processing a CSV file

Tags: azure-functions, powershell-core

I have a scheduled daily Azure function in Powershell core, that downloads a CSV file of records. I need to process each record and sent it to an external API endpoint.

This endpoint will only accept 1 request every 5 seconds, and there can be hundreds or thousands of records in the CSV file.

I need to loop through the excel file and add each record to some for of queue that can be processed no faster than one record every 5 seconds.

What Azure service would I use to handle the queueing?

Comment: As you said the endpoint can only accept 1 request per 5s, so within 24h, there're at most 17280 pieces of data could be accepted, and you also said that there're many records, so why not trying to create a new endpoint which could accept csv file directly?

Comment: I have no control over the external api endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) or [Azure Storage Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction) to queue each record for processing.

But to ensure only one record is processing every 5 seconds, instead of leveraging a queue-triggered function, using a timer-triggered function (or [logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)) that fetches one message and processes it.